# Please identify this horror movie about ghosts that only attack in the dark

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I remember watching an movie when I was younger, at least a good 7 years, it was about this family who moved into an haunted house (of course) but the ghosts were different, they could only attack in the dark, they would pose as members of the family to try to get them to turn off the light so they could attack. Some scenes I remember are the kids finding a old family picture under the stairs and when they looked away the faces in the picture turned all scary: the dad or the brother had a breathing problem and they had to poke a hole in his neck with a pen to get him to breath again: ended with kids getting out but the girls boyfriend who picked them up was actually an ghost posing as the boyfriend and then drove under a dark bridge. 
It is driving me crazy that I can't find this movie, please help!

Comment: Sounds very similar to [Thir13en Ghosts (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245674/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're describing [The Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkness_%282002_film%29) from 2002 with Anna Paquin and Lena Olin.

> Forty years after an unfinished occult ritual resulted in the disappearance of six children, an American family has moved into a never-before inhabited house in Spain. The mother, Maria (Olin), wants to get the place in order, while the father, Mark (Glen), goes to work, and their children, teenager Regina (Paquin) and her younger brother Paul (Enquist), try to settle into their daily routines.

And in the end:

> Regina races back to her home to find her father in the midst of another nervous breakdown, choking on pills as the eclipse begins. **Maria tries to perform a tracheotomy on him**, but is unable to bring herself to make the cut. Regina volunteers to, but inadvertently causes his death. Since Regina genuinely loved Mark, the ritual is finally complete. **The darkness then takes the form of Regina and Paul, convincing their mother to turn off the lights. The darkness kills Maria, and then takes the form of Regina's friend Carlos, who picks them up in his car. The real Carlos arrives at the house, only to be killed by the darkness. The movie ends with the fake Carlos driving Regina and Paul into a dark tunnel, where it is implied that the darkness kills Regina and Paul.**

Here's the trailer: